# Connection between multiple clients to a single server in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, websocket, client-server

I need to create 20 clients which make requests simultaneously to a server in nodejs using websocket. I am able to create the connection between a single server and a client using websocket. But when it comes to creating 20 clients, I am not having any idea to proceed. Please give any suggestions to proceed.

Comment: You could use socket.io lib. See here https://github.com/socketio/socket.io

Comment: I am using websocket for establishing the connection. It is same as using socket.io. I am concerned about creating those 20 clients for this application. Does 20 clients refer to creating 20 html pages in the application?

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't need to create 20 html pages. Same HTML page can be loaded by multiple clients.

On server-side, the 'request' event will fire every time a client connects to your websocket server. Your websocket server will be able to handle multiple clients out of the box. However, you will need to ascertain 'which' client this particular request originated from. That can be done by using tokens or credentials, or any other custom protocol that you want to establish between your client and server.

Check the server-side usage example for `websocket` module here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket#server-example

Comment: Can you pls elaborate how the same html page can be loaded by multiple clients? Any code snippet will be helpful.

Comment: You don't need any extra code to load a webpage in multiple clients. Start your browser, open the webpage (html) using server's address. Open a new tab or window, enter same web address again, html should load fine in this new tab too.

Comment: Thanks. I had used this approach earlier. Problem with this approach is I was not able to differentiate between the clients since the same port was used by all the clients. I need to prioritize the clients and handle requests based on their priority. Can you shed some light on it?

Comment: The `websocket` library allows the client to pass extra parameters. 
Check the `Client.connect` function documentation here https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/blob/master/docs/WebSocketClient.md. You can pass 'extra' data in headers or query param. Let's assume the client sends the logged-in user id using either of the methods. On server side in your 'request' event handler, you will extract the user-id, and take action based on that. Please note, in real world, client would almost certainly send an auth token or jwt token, and not simple user-id since that can easily be mocked.

Comment: Your explanation looks good. I will address this problem through this approach. Thanks for your help. @elem4th